# Print the emacs package name that a function belongs to

Tags: elisp, emacs24

In elisp,  `M-x find-function funcName`
is there to go to the function definition. But, how to print the package name that a function belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in library `help-fns.el` contains `find-lisp-object-file-name`.  If you call this with a function name and `type` set to `nil` it will print the full file name of the file containing the definition.
On my system

```
(find-lisp-object-file-name 'find-function nil)
```

returns

> "/Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/emacs-lisp/find-func.el"

which you can strip down as required.  Note this behaves well on undefinded functions

> ```
> (find-lisp-object-file-name 'I-dont-exist nil)
> nil
> (find-lisp-object-file-name 'icicle-find-file nil)
> "/Users/swann/.emacs.d/elpa/icicles-20141215.1749/icicles-cmd1.el"
> ```

Items in packages will be found under in one of the directories in `package-directory-list` and `package-user-dir`.  By default the latter is `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.  Under such a directory the given package is a subdirectory with name `package-name-VERSION`.